# Lookaheand & Lookafter in grep in unix terminal

Tags: regex, unix, grep, regex-lookarounds

I have a quick question, I just wonder how to use lookahead and lookafter in grep in unix terminal? I want to know how to turn on the special meaning of ?= and ?<= and so on.

I hope you guys could kindly give me some suggestion.

Many thanks in advance. :p

Answer (score 6):

you need `grep -P`, to use PCRE.

for example:

```
kent$  echo "David Dai"|grep -Po "(?<=v)i.*(?=D)"
id
```

Comment: Hi Kent, thank you so much for your quick response, I will try later. Hope you have a good day.